# OpenGL ES 2.0 Point Sprites Size

Tags: opengl, 3d, android, opengl-es

I am trying to draw point sprites in OpenGL ES 2.0, but all my points end up with a size of 1 pixel...even when I set gl_PointSize to a high value in my vertex shader.

How can I make my point sprites bigger?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 supports Point Sprites; i use them for particles. Just use `glDrawElements` with `GL_POINTS`.

In vertex shader, you set the size with `gl_PointSize` and use `gl_PointCoord` in fragment shader for texture mapping.

My vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMvp;
uniform float uThickness;

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord; 
attribute vec4 aColor;

varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vec4 position = uMvp * vec4(aPosition.xyz, 1.);
    vColor = aColor;
    gl_PointSize = uThickness;
    gl_Position =  position;  
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() 
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, gl_PointCoord) * vColor;
}
```

If you are on Android, you can look [my french Tutorial](http://www.scigems.org/downloads/Articles/Episode1.php). There is a full project with point sprites.

Comment: Don't forget to explicitly specify `float` precision in fragment shaders - they don't have default `float` precision and on some drivers such shaders may fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, glLineWidth() makes points larger too:

```
    GLES20.glLineWidth(8); // Make the edges (and points!) thicker
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 38);// 38 is number of my vertexes
```

Comment: You are a hero. Bob bless.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGLES 2.0 does not directly support point sprites.  You can either [texture your glPoints](http://klazuka.tumblr.com/post/249698151/point-sprites-and-opengl-es-2-0) or manually create a camera-facing and camera-aligned quad centered on a point.

Comment: False. use GL_POINTS and gl_PointSize in vertex shader

Comment: @Ellis Well he kind of said that.  If you look at the link posted it talks about the GL ES 1 part that was deprecated, and how to "texture your glPoints"